# Links inside span div not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am implementing a live user search in my website. I have written the following code to display the users name as links. But the links are not working they are just like plain text.(Pointer shows up when I hover on it).

HTML:

```
    <div id="search">
    <input type="text" id="fr_name" name="fr_name" placeholder="Search a friend">
    </div>
    <div class="results">
        <span id="search_result"></span>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
function search_results(search_value){
    $.post('/fantasy/findfriends.php',
           {fr_name:search_value},
           function(data)
           {
               $('#search_result').html(data) ;
           }) ;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#fr_name').val()==='')
    {
        $('#search_result').hide() ;
    }
}) ;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fr_name').blur(function(){
        $('#search_result').hide() ;
    });
}) ;


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fr_name').keyup(function(){
        if($('#fr_name').val()==='')
        {
            $('#search_result').hide() ;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#search_result').show() ;
            search_results($('#fr_name').val()) ;
        }
    }) ;
}) ;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fr_name').focus(function(){
        if($('#fr_name').val()==='')
        {
            $('#search_result').hide() ;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#search_result').show() ;
            search_results($('#fr_name').val()) ;
        }
    }) ;
}) ;
```

PHP

```
<?php
include_once 'php_inc/core.inc.php' ;
include_once 'php_inc/connect.inc.php' ;
include_once 'php_inc/getdata.inc.php' ;

if (logged_in())
{
    $value=$_POST['fr_name'] ;
    $counter=0 ;
    if(isset($_POST['fr_name']))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['fr_name']))
        {
            $name=$_POST['fr_name'] ;
            $query="SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'" ;
            $query_run=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) ;
            $query_num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($query_run) ;

            if ($query_num_rows>0 && $counter<8)
            {
                for($count=0;$count<$query_num_rows;$count++)
                {
                    $fri_email=mysqli_result($query_run,$count,'email') ;
                    $query_result_name=mysqli_result($query_run,$count,'name') ;
                    $query_result_email=mysqli_result($query_run,$count,'email') ;
                    echo '<a href="www.google.com">' . $query_result_name . '<a/><br/>'. $query_result_email . '<br/><br/>';
                    $counter++ ;
                }
                echo '<a href="allresults.php">See all results</a>' ;
            }
            if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
            {
                $query="SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE email='$value'" ;
                $query_run=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) ;
                $query_num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($query_run) ;
                if ($query_num_rows>0)
                {
                    for($i=0;$i<$query_num_rows;$i++)
                    {
                            $query_result_name=mysqli_result($query_run,$i,'name') ;
                            $query_result_email=mysqli_result($query_run,$i,'email') ;
                            echo $query_result_name.'<br>'.$query_result_email.'<br><br>' ;
                            $counter++ ;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($counter==0)
            {
                echo 'No results found' ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'No results found' ;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

CSS

```
.results{
z-index:3 ;
}

.results:hover{
background-color:#ffffff ; 
}

.results a:link{
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
color: #ffffff ;
text-decoration: none ;
}
```

Please feel free to ask any questions. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Where are you building the `anchor` tag for usernames? The only `anchor` tag here is for see all users.

Comment: create an `anchor` tag with `var anchor = $('<a/>').attr('href','your_link')` then append to desired element like i.e: `$('#yourDivId').append(anchor)`.

Comment: @Kami sry I was editing my code and forgot to add the link in this one I have echoed it in php.Like this: echo <a href="www.google.com">$query_result_name.'</a><br>'.$query_result_email.'<br><br>' ;[google is just for example]

Comment: @albciff I am new to this. So can you please explain in more detail. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help

Comment: @ArunNalla - That code appears to be incorrect. There are no quotes around the first part of the link.  It should be `echo '<a href="www.google.com">' . $query_result_name . '<a/><br/>'. $query_result_email . '<br/><br/>';`, is this another typo?

Comment: @Kami Sorry Sorry that was a typo. I assure no more errors now I have checked. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show an example of the rendered HTML.

Comment: Sorry @ArunNalla at first I thought that you were adding the `anchor` through jquery... but you're adding it with php, sorry but in this case I've no idea how to do so.

Comment: Your code should work as is - Is there anything overlaid on the links that might be preventing clicks? Try removing unrelated elements from the page.

Comment: @Kami Thanks I finally found the answer there was a div overlapping .Every thing is sorted now and it's working fine. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try after comment this code in jquery.

`$('#fr_name').blur(function(){ $('#search_result').hide() ; });`

Comment: @ArunNalla : Are you not getting redirection page or enabled to click ? or link is not displaying ? 
Remove a:link color style #ffffff also.

Comment: Link is getting displayed I am unable to click it. If I remove the styling I am seeing a normal html link (blue and underlined) but I it is not clickable. @dHaRa uMaraniYa